# Covariance in terms of variance

Tags: probability, statistics, covariance

Is it true that?

> $$ Cov(X, Y) = \frac{Var(X) \; Var(Y)}{Var(X) + Var(Y)} $$

And if so, please prove or explain why this is so.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that is or isn't true?

Comment: No, it is not true in general. We don't even have to look at the details of the proposed formula: the covariance is not determined by the variances.

Comment: No, it is not. Namely, The RHS depends only on the laws of $X$ and $Y$ separately, while the LHS depends on the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$.

Comment: the covariance of two independent random variables is $0$, while it is $c \ var(Y)  $ if $X = c Y$ (the full dependent case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not hold. Namely, if $X=Y$

$$LHS =Var(X)\\ RHS = \frac12 Var(X)$$

Comment: While if $X$ and $Y$ are iid, $LHS=0, RHS=\frac12 Var(X)$